# what are the recommended resources to help create an enterprise level document management system using sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to create a document management system of enterprise level in sharepoint. Which book or resources could point me in right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can read documentation from MS here

http://search.microsoft.com/en-us/results.aspx?q=sharepoint+plan+record+management